# Incorrect boolean outcome using isWeekEnd method with Calendar instance

Tags: java, calendar, boolean, logical-operators

None of the existing threads helped me understand why the date that I enter in the main method (2016, 25, 11) which is a Friday is popping up as true for my method isWeekend(). I've seen in the other threads people talking about setting the Calendar's first day of week to Monday but I don't see how that would change my results

```
public static boolean isWeekend(Calendar userDate){
    if (userDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || 
    userDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
        return true;
    else return false;
    } 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.set(2016, 25, 11);
   System.out.println(CalendarBankHoliday.isWeekend(c1));
}
```

Please can someone help me understand this

Edited: it correctly displays 2016,26,11 as a weekend(true) but 2016, 27, 11 as weekday(false)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate at all, the answer for my question is not the same as the one you've provided. Im asking for a boolean using Calendar static values not iterating through a week and skipping it if its saturday or sunday, the methods are completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. The [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class works with 0-based months: January = 0, February = 1, etc.
2. The [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) method takes the year, month, and day in that order, not year, day, and month.

The statement `c1.set(2016, 25, 11);` actually sets the date to February 11, 2018 (a Sunday), because 25 = 2×12 + 1, so the year is incremented by 2 and the month is set to February. Similarly, the statement `c1.set(2016, 26, 11);` actually sets the date to March 11, 2018 (also a Sunday).

To set `c1` to November 25, 2016, change 11 to 10, and swap the second and third arguments:

```
c1.set(2016, 10, 25); // Friday, November 25, 2016
```

If you're hard-coding the date,  you can also use a static constant for clarity:

```
c1.set(2016, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 25);
```

Comment: is there anyway to edit this to make it so january is 1?

Comment: That's just the way the Calendar class works. If you're accepting the month from the user, then subtract 1 before passing it to the `set` method.

Comment: ok thanks, its just that I have a premade list of Calendar instances with bank holiday dates inside of them, I guess I have to take 1 away from the month of those also?

Comment: Yes. Also note that you've mixed up the month and day arguments; the order should be "year, month, day", not "year, day, month".

Comment: okay thanks for your help!

Comment: just seen the Calendar.NOVEMBER instead of hard coding 10, cheers for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using the legacy `Calendar` and `Date` classes.  In Java 8, there is a new package called `java.time` which has much nicer classes to deal with dates.

In your case, because it's just a date (without a time), [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is appropriate for your use case.  Nice easy methods to check days of the week, and it also attempts months so that January = 1.